# Laravel regex for friendly url with unknown lenght of string dash separated

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-routing

in my laravel app I use this route to catch friendly urls for categories:

```
Route::get('/category/{friendlyUrl}', 'CategoryController@index')->where(['friendlyUrl' => '^([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)']);
```

Problem is that friendly url contains string with dashes and category id. I use this param to split string in php to get $id.

Is it possible to catch $id from those urls by using laravel route instead of processing url in php:

```
/category/meble-barcelona-42479
/category/meble-do-kuchnii-43344
/category/some-random-url-lenght-ending-up-with-id-42479
```

Lenght of friendly url string is unknown and it always ends up with dash and id.
Expected route should look like:

```
Route::get('/category/{friendlyUrl}{id}', 'CategoryController@index')
or
Route::get('/category/{friendlyUrl}-{id}', 'CategoryController@index')
```

Is it possible to do that by using some sort of regex?

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: who generates the url?? if that is you, why don't you use the standard `category/{id}/{slug}` route format??

Comment: Because 20000+ urls are indexed in google and i cannot change them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this exactly the way you want to but you can change it so it's more hidden in your code by using a custom route binding:

In `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
Route::bind('friendlyUrl', function($value)
{
    $parts = explode('-', $value);
    $id = array_pop($parts);
    return Category::findOrFail($id);
});
```

Then your route can be:

```
public function index(Category $friendlyUrl) {
    // $friendlyUrl should have the correct Category based on the id at the end of the URL
}
```

This may not be exactly what you want, but it's at least a re-usable way of getting the category from the slug-id part.